# Executes a function until it returns a nil, collecting its values into a list

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp

I got this idea from [XKCD's Hofstadter comic](http://xkcd.com/917/); what's the best way to create a conditional loop in (any) Lisp dialect that executes a function until it returns `NIL` at which time it collects the returned values into a list.

For those who haven't seen the joke, it's goes that Douglas Hofstadter's “eight-word” autobiography consists of only six words: “I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym” containing continuation of the joke: (some odd meta-paraprosdokian?) “Is Meta” — the joke being that the autobiography is actually “I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym Is Meta”. But why not go deeper?

Assume the acronymizing function `META` that creates an acronym from a string and splits it into words, returns `NIL` if the string contains but one word:

```
(meta "I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym") ⇒ "Is Meta"
(meta (meta "I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym")) ⇒ "Im"
(meta (meta (meta "I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym"))) ⇒ NIL

(meta "GNU is Not UNIX") ⇒ "GNU"
(meta (meta "GNU is Not UNIX")) ⇒ NIL
```

Now I'm looking for how to implement a function so that:

```
(so-function #'meta "I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym") 
⇒ ("I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym" "Is Meta" "Im")
(so-function #'meta "GNU is Not Unix")
⇒ ("GNU is Not Unix" "GNU")
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Jordan's answer "cheats" by being wired for only specific cases.  For a general purpose <code>(meta)</code>, you would have to decide where word boundaries are.  You could use a dictionary file.

Comment: @compman, his question specifically said to assume the existence of `meta` so I wouldn't call it "cheating". Still, you have a point. I'm not quite sure *how* to decide where the word boundaries are though, even given a dictionary. One particular problem would be how to decide you were looking at one word and should terminate.

EDIT: One way might be to say "if this word is in my dictionary or if I cannot split this word into any number of subwords such that they are all in my dictionary, terminate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy.  I don't want to write a solution, so instead I will -- but it'll be the crappy elisp version, which might lead to unexpected enlightenment if you'll follow through:

```
(defun so-function (f str)
  (let (x '())
    (while str (setq x (cons str x)) (setq str (funcall f str)))
    (reverse x)))
```

To try this out you'll need that `meta`, but I don't know how you'd decide where to put the spaces, so instead I'll fake it:

```
(defun meta (x)
  (cadr (assoc x '(("I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym" "Is Meta")
                   ("Is Meta" "Im")
                   ("GNU is Not UNIX" "GNU")))))
```

This makes the code that you want work.  As for the enlightenment -- try to write it so instead of what you want, `so-function` will be a higher order function -- one that will work like this:

```
(funcall (so-function #'meta) "GNU is Not UNIX")
```

or, in Scheme:

```
((so-function meta) "GNU is Not UNIX")
```

The big hint here is that you can't do it in plain elisp (at least not without tricks from the `cl` library).  To get full credit, avoid the mutations -- this will lead to the natural way you'd write it in Scheme, and might even look more readable than the `setq` version.

Comment: Shouldn't your Emacs Lisp version function call be `(funcall #'so-function #'meta "GNUS is Not UNIX")` which returns `("GNU is Not UNIX" "GNU")`? (and similarly `(funcall #'so-function #'meta "I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym")` ⇒ `("I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym" "Is Meta" "Im")`)

Comment: Or just `(so-function #'meta autobiography)` like in Jordan Wade's answer

Comment: No -- see the beginning of that part, where I said "try ti write it so ..." -- that's the exercise I gave out!

Answer (score 1):

Threw this together and it seems to work:

```
(defun collect-until-null (function initial-value)
  "Collects INITIAL-VALUE and the results of repeatedly applying FUNCTION to
   INITIAL-VALUE into a list.  When the result is NIL, iteration stops."
  (if initial-value
      (cons initial-value
            (collect-until-null function (funcall function initial-value)))))
```

Using a slightly modified version of the `meta` Eli Barzilay posted,

```
(defun meta (x)
  (cadr (assoc x
               '(("I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym" "Is Meta")
                 ("Is Meta" "Im")
                 ("GNU is Not UNIX" "GNU"))
               :test #'equal))) ;strings with the same characters aren't EQL
```

I get the result you were looking for.

```
CL-USER> (collect-until-null #'meta "I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym")
("I'm So Meta, Even This Acronym" "Is Meta" "Im")

CL-USER> (collect-until-null #'meta "GNU is Not UNIX")
("GNU is Not UNIX" "GNU")
```

---

**Edit**: @Rainer Joswig pointed out that `collect-until-null` will exhaust the stack if given a sufficiently large sequence. Below is Rainer's iterative version without this problem.

```
(defun collect-until-null-iter (function initial-value)
  "Collects INITIAL-VALUE and the results of repeatedly applying FUNCTION to
   INITIAL-VALUE into a list.  When the result is NIL, iteration stops."
  (loop for result = initial-value then (funcall function result)
        while result collect result))
```

Comment: @Rainer Joswig, could you be more specific? I re-ran it in a fresh SBCL instance and had no problems.

Comment: @Rainer, that isn't helping me figure out what's wrong. Could you please post the *exact* code you're using that's causing an overflow? (Or link if it's too long for a comment?)

Comment: (collect-until-null (let ((n 20000)) (lambda (o) (unless (zerop n) (decf n)))) t)     You may need to change N for your Lisp implementation. The one I tested it with has a stack overflow for n = 2300.

Comment: @Rainer, I get it now and edited the answer with (what I think is) a tail-recursive version. Could you check it out and tell me if (1) your Lisp exhausts the stack with the new version and (2) if I'm doing anything non-idiomatic? I'm self-taught so it wouldn't surprise me if I did something that would make an more experienced person go "WTF?".

Comment: This does the same as your code, without the need for the slightly non-standard TCO support: (loop for result = obj then (funcall func result) while result collect result) . Note also that there is the same problem as with your versions: the initial value is collected - without the function being applied to it, which is not what is documented.

Comment: @Rainer, replaced the TR version with yours and fixed the documentation to say that the initial value is in the returned list. Thanks!