# Idiomatic Ruby - Execute a function until it returns a nil, collecting its values into a list

Tags: ruby, list, while-loop, return-value, null

I stole my title from this post: [Executes a function until it returns a nil, collecting its values into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510681/executes-a-function-until-it-returns-a-nil-collecting-its-values-into-a-list)

That question refers to Lisp and is, frankly, over my head. However, I think that his question--translated into Ruby--is exactly my own:

> What's the best way to create a conditional loop in [Ruby] that executes a function until it returns NIL at which time it collects the returned values into a list?

My current, clunky approach is this:

```
def foo
   ret = Array.new
   x = func() # parenthesis for clarity (I'm not a native Ruby coder...)
   until x.nil?
     ret << x
     x = func() 
   end
   ret
end
```

This code snippet will do what I want...but I know there is a cleaner, more idiomatically Ruby approach...right?

Comment: I would be interested if you could provide a real-world case where you would use such a method.

Comment: @Phrogz This sounds like an iterable generator to me, and it's a common design pattern, especially in functional programs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Funny how nobody suggested [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) and its `take_while` method, to me it seems just fit:

```
# example function that sometimes returns nil
def func
  r = rand(5)
  r == 0 ? nil : r
end

# wrap function call into lazy enumerator
enum = Enumerator.new{|y|
  loop {
    y << func()
  }
}

# take from it until we bump into a nil
arr = enum.take_while{|elem|
  !elem.nil?
}

p arr
#=>[3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1]
```

Comment: +1, very nice solution, `Enumerator` is under-used for things like this.

Comment: Thought about a similar approach, but don't liked the end result, because it was already confusing myself 1 minute after writing it.

Comment: Because this code doesn't feel like Ruby at all. Valid code != beautiful code.

Comment: @ream88 -- I disagree. Ruby has functional features, so functional approach to a typical functional problem seems right. I would only use do-end blocks instead of parens here and there ;)

Comment: Instead of `enum.take_while { |elem| !elem.nil? }`, `elem.take_while(&:itself)`

Answer (score 9):

I guess this looks more like Ruby:

```
def foo
  r = nil; [].tap { |a| a << r until (r = yield).nil? }
end
```

Comment: I like this one, cleaner than mine.

Comment: If you declare x=nil in the method arguments, it will be a one-liner :)

Comment: Note that these answers do not exactly match the requirements, which call for `nil` only as a stop condition (not `false`).

Comment: It's pretty, but because it mishandles false it does not satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Should be easy enough to fix with `until (result = yield).nil?` shouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you guys, was already late yesterday ;) New version is fixed!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
def foo
  arr = []
  while true
    x = yield
    break if x.nil?
    arr << x
  end
  arr
end
```

Usage:

```
foo { doStuff }
foo &bar
```

Comment: I think it's more idiomatic in Ruby to use `loop{ ... }` instead of `while true ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally write it like this, so that you can pass a block that calls a function or does whatever you want:

```
def gather
  [].tap do |collection|
    result=true; i=0
    until result.nil?
        unless (result=yield(i)).nil?
        collection << result
      end
      i += 1
      end
  end
end


# Silly test
$letters = *('a'..'z')
$current = -1
def next_char(max)
  $letters[$current+=1] if $current<max
end
some = gather{ next_char(10) }
p some
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]

some = gather{ |i| $letters[i] if i<=10 }
p some
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]
```

Note that you could write the method like this:

```
def gather
  [].tap do |result|
    x = true
    result << x unless (x=yield).nil? until x.nil?
  end
end
```

…but I personally don't find that to be very readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were pretty close to begin with.

```
def gather
  ret = []
  while x = yield
    ret << x
  end
  ret
end
```

The only trick here is understanding that the assignment "x = yield" returns the value of x, so "while x = yield" loops while x isn't nil/false. Not to be confused with "while x == yield"...